# does Datagridview on XP have visual problems

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows, winforms, datagridview

datagridview on vb.net is looking very wrong on xp, picture boxes inside the grid are not showing and if I change the width of a columns u see the lines marking on the screen until u refresh... only on windows xp.

This wasnt happening before on xp though, I did a lot of changes to code and when I later put them on a client with xp it showed.

I already tried going through what I changed but I couldn't figure it out. An older build of the application doesn't show this problem which means its definetly the change in the code.
I know I can remove the hardware acceleration and that would work, but I want to know what may cause this to happen codewise.

Below is two images the first from windows 7 and the second from xp... u can see what Im talking about

My question is: What usually causes something like this codewise?

[image: Datagridview on windows 7]
[image: Datagridview on windows xp]

Comment: If the problems appeared after you made changes to the code, you should look for problems in the code, not the OS. Eg, are you using platform specific paths?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as I said I already tried going through code. Regarding the paths, if you mean for the image its one image and its local. The problem is with all datagridviews throughout the application.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. All I want to know is what usually causes this

Comment: It's impossible to help without looking at the code. Platform specific paths are just one possibility, eg looking for the image in "C:\Program Files (x86)" when the XP installation is in "C:\Program Files". How do you load the image? Did you try debugging the application? Do you log errors? Was there an exception logged? Does the image exist in the path you specify? You mentioned hardware acceleration, yet Windows Forms doesn't use acceleration. Does your XP machine have a faulty or outdated driver? How did you determine that the grid works without acceleration? How did you disable it?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the image is imported as a local resource directly in to the datagridview and it has always been that way. That didn't change when I made code changes. No there are no errors. Its not just about the image. The whole table looks different. If you resize the column width you see the marked lines still there.  When I set the acceleration to None it was fixed that's how I know. Here is the link that says how:
http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/06/troubleshoot-grapics-rendering-issues.html
Note: I am using winforms not wpf as the example in the link

Comment: Is this happening on all XP machines? Why are the font sizes so different?

Comment: Thats because its probably using the visual style for XP. Also on the XP machines check the default screen settimgs ...

Comment: Do you do any owner-drawing?

Comment: Standard control appearance will vary depending on the schema selected in windows and windows version. There were and always will be differences between OSes, so if you want your application to support XP and 7, you better make sure you are able to test both. [Virtual XP](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) on 7 will do good. Regarding image problem, maybe they are in a wrong format. I have similar *problem* (but I don't really care) where transparency is drawn in black color on XP. Redraw problem means something in code. Show it.

Comment: @TaW so far on 2/2 xp machines. Font and rowheight are set dynamically by user. There are no owner drawing.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR As I said nothing changed on the machines. The change was made to code.

Comment: @Sinatr As I said it was working before.